# Parsing unformatted string in python

Tags: python, linux, shell, kubernetes, scripting

I am a newbie to python. Able to get the data in the following format :-

Here is the code :-

```
import paramiko
import json
class Remote_SSH:
    def __init__(self,name,command):
        self.name = name
        self.command = command

    def sshcont(self):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname = self.name, username='root')
        ssh.invoke_shell()
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command (self.command)
        cmdout = (stdout.read())
        return cmdout
        ssh.close()

    def ssh_print(self):
        list_logs = []
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname = self.name, username='root')
        sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command (self.command)
        for logs in stdout:
            print logs.strip("\n")
            list_logs.append(logs)
        ssh.close()
        return list_logs

kubectl_pods_data = Remote_SSH('IP_ADDRESS','kubectl get pods --namespace prelude').sshcont()
print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
print kubectl_pods_data
print type(kubectl_pods_data)
print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
```

here is the output

```
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
abx-service-app-78968c4446-dz586               1/1     Running   0          34d
abx-service-app-78968c4446-mn8jz               1/1     Running   0          34d
abx-service-app-78968c4446-rd8xq               1/1     Running   0          34d
approval-service-5c869c44b6-8vxwd              1/1     Running   0          34d
approval-service-5c869c44b6-j6zgr              1/1     Running   0          34d
approval-service-5c869c44b6-nqxv9              1/1     Running   0          34d

<type 'str'>
```

I want to print the value in name column if the corresponding value in not running . I tried converting it to dictionary, but could not do so . Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: kubectl_pods_data = Remote_SSH('ip_Address','kubectl get pods --namespace prelude').sshcont() .  This command is used to get the data, remote_ssh is a module that I wrote to SSH onto the machine and run the command

Comment: please include the code in your post, not in the comment.

Comment: Done , I've updated the question with my code

Comment: So your `kubectl_pods_data` is just one string, although nicely formatted?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: @RaghavChadha : _I tried converting it to dictionary_ : Where does this happen in your code?

Comment: Why are you not using official [python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert your string in a list of lists of strings, where every sublist represents a row in your table:

```
lst_data=[x.split() for x in kubectl_pods_data.split('\n')]
```

At this point you may transform this structure as you like, or even use it directly: e.g.

```
for row in lst_data:
    if row[2] != 'Running':
        print(row[0])
```